# WPF String formatting the contents of a list

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list box which I populate with a list of type Foo, which contains the following properties: Name and ID.

I am binding it to a list box control. The problem is that I am getting "**MyNamespace.Model.Foo**" over an over in my list box. Is it possible for me to do extract the contents of my Foo list and display them in my view? How would I go doing something like that?

Here is where I am populating my list:

Window.Main:

```
    void Load()
        {
          var result = my_model.GetData();

          foreach (var x in result)
          {
            Foo foo = new Foo{ Id = x.ID, Name = x.Name };
            ViewModel.Foo.Add(foo);

          }
        }
```

My View:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbMyCollection" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Foo}}">        
      </ListBox>
```

Comment: why am I down voted? I just asked a question, provided code and I would've fixed my question upon request. Why is this community so harsh with some of us? I just wanted to learn.

Answer (score 1):

[DisplayMemberPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbMyCollection" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Foo}}"
         DisplayMemberPath="Name">
```

I will delete once once the question is a declared a duplicate.